# Как правильно реализовать авторизацию между сервисами?

Tags: golang

У меня куча сервисов. Сейчас они работают «в открытую». Мне это не подходит по понятным причинам. Я думаю сделать проверку при помощи `hash`, в который буду ставить секретный ключ и передаваемые данные (вот так просто). Я думаю, что это очень «дыряво». Как делают обычно такое?

Answer (score 1):

Я заюзал HMAC. Википедия говорит что надёжно.